# How to use .append() with openpyxl to scrape content of multiple web pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a code to scrape the script of "The Fellowship Of The Ring" from a website and paste it into an Excel spreadsheet. I have started by creating the code to do this for one page and everything was fine, however, when I added a loop to go through all the pages that contain the script, I encountered an issue where the content of the spreadsheet is overwritten every time a new page is scraped.

Looking at the documentation for `openpyxl`, I understand that I should be using `.append()`, and I tried to do that, inside the `if` loop after I create the variable `fname = 'script.xlsx'` (not shown on this code). It goes without saying that it didn't work, I ended up having a spreadsheet with only the content of the first cell of the first page.

I also read some old threads that suggest specifying the cell  with `.cell()` where to paste the text, however, I'm not sure it would be the best solution, as the number of rows of the tables is different for each web page.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# divides url into 3 parts to loop through the pages
url1 = 'http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/fellowshipofthering'
url2 = 'to'
url3 = '.php'
# main loop: browses the various pages of the script
# f: first number in page url
for f in range(1, 38, 4):
    # s: second number in page url
    s = f + 3
    # combines the url
    url = url1 + str(f) + url2 + str(s) + url3
    driver.get(url)
    # finds length of row and column tags on webpage
    rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr"))
    columns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr[3]/td"))
    # divides url into 3 parts to loop through the rows and columns
    first = "//*[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr["
    second = "]/td["
    third = "]"
    # loops through the rows (r) and columns (c) of each page
    # try/except are used to consider rows with only 1 column
    for r in range(1, rows+1):
        for c in range(1, columns+1):
            try:
                # combines the xpath of each cell of the table
                final = first + str(r) + second + str(c) + third
                # stores the content of each cell in a variable (data)
                data = driver.find_element_by_xpath(final).text
                # writes content of table in an Excel spreadsheet
                fname = 'script.xlsx'
                if os.path.exists(fname):
                    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
                    worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
                else:
                    workbook = Workbook()
                    worksheet = workbook.active
                worksheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value = data
                workbook.save(fname)
            except:
                continue
# closes Chrome
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- The row in the excel sheet does not match the row in the web page. The excel row should be set separately.
- Opening and saving the sheet at each row slows the process considerably. Opening once per web page should be enough in case there is an issue.

Here's the updated code:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("disable-plugins")
options.experimental_options["useAutomationExtension"] = False  # prevent load error - Error Loading Extension - Failed to load extension from ... - Could not load extension from ... Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

# divides url into 3 parts to loop through the pages
url1 = 'http://www.ageofthering.com/atthemovies/scripts/fellowshipofthering'
url2 = 'to'
url3 = '.php'
# main loop: browses the various pages of the script
# f: first number in page url
rpaste = 1  # paste data in excel
for f in range(1, 38, 4):
    # s: second number in page url
    s = f + 3
    # combines the url
    url = url1 + str(f) + url2 + str(s) + url3
    driver.get(url)
    # finds length of row and column tags on webpage
    rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr"))
    columns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr[3]/td"))
    # divides url into 3 parts to loop through the rows and columns
    first = "//*[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr["
    second = "]/td["
    third = "]"
    fname = 'script.xlsx'
    if os.path.exists(fname):
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
        worksheet = workbook['Sheet']
    else:
        workbook = Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
    # loops through the rows (r) and columns (c) of each page
    # try/except are used to consider rows with only 1 column
    print('Paste Row', rpaste)
    for r in range(1, rows+1):
        while worksheet.cell(rpaste, 1).value:   # get next empty row in sheet
            rpaste += 1
        for c in range(1, columns+1):
            try:
                # combines the xpath of each cell of the table
                final = first + str(r) + second + str(c) + third
                # stores the content of each cell in a variable (data)
                data = driver.find_element_by_xpath(final).text
                if c == 1 and "Scene" in data and "~" in data: # add extra empty row if new scene
                    rpaste += 1
                # writes content of table in an Excel spreadsheet
                worksheet.cell(rpaste, column=c).value = data
            except:
                continue
    workbook.save(fname)
# closes Chrome
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is what I was after. Now I noticed another issue, from "scene 25" it stops writing the content of the second column, I checked the xpath structure and is the same as the other pages, so I don't understand what's happening there. Should I create a separate topic to ask about this?